# Improvements on generating monero wallets securely?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, security, cold-storage, best-practices

My current process of generating monero wallets:

1. Use an air-gapped RaspberryPi
2. Use `monero-wallet-cli` to generate a wallet
3. Record mnemonic on paper only
4. Record partial address for reference on paper (e.g. 49egIz-----ee8ZX1)
5. Record full address/view-key in a computer `txt` file

For additional redundancy I am thinking of also encrypting the mnemonic/address/view-key:

`openssl rand -base64 64 > password.txt`

`echo "exit" | ./monero-wallet-cli --mnemonic-language=English --generate-new-wallet=mywallet --password-file password.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -out mywallet.txt.enc`

The above creates and wallet and outputs the cli content directly to an encrypted file (openssl prompts/verifies a password).

... and to decrypt:

`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -a -in mywallet.txt.enc -out mywallet.txt`

I'd like some feedback and suggestions for improvements, thank you.